# delete original array pointer after copy sets first 3 bytes to 0

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino, delete-operator

The following program works untill a buffersize of something like 135.
If the buffer gets any larger, the first 3.5 bytes get printed out as 0.
(on a MKR1000 arduino)

```
uint8_t* bufferOut;
size_t sizeOut;

void SendMessage()
{
    fillBuffer();
    sendBuffer();
}

void fillBuffer()
{
    sizeOut = 12; //just an example
    uint8_t* tempBuffer2 = new uint8_t[sizeOut];
    bufferOut = tempBuffer2;
    delete[] tempBuffer2;
}

void sendBuffer()
{
    Serial.Write(bufferOut, sizeOut);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Would std::vector be more suitable here?

Thanks!

Comment: `delete[] tempBuffer2;` - what do you suppose that leaves `bufferOut` pointing to ? You just deleted the memory behind the pointer you just allocated two lines prior, and stored in `bufferOut` one line prior, leaving it *dangling*. Any further dereference invoking *undefined behavior*. And yes, `std::vector` is nearly always more suitable to manual memory management.

Comment: We need actual, complete code. As it stands the code doesn't make sense. You don't use the memory between allocation and deallocation, so why are you allocating it in the first place? Also, what does the first function have to do with the second?

Comment: _delete original array pointer after copy sets first 3 bytes to 0_ — There is no legal way how to find this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> bufferOut = tempBuffer2;
> delete[] tempBuffer2;
> ```

After these operations, `bufferOut` is an invalid pointer because the object that it used to point to was destroyed. That in itself doesn't cause any undefined behaviour, but presumably you've simply failed to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and the problem is actually caused by you later using the invalid pointer.

> Would std::vector be more suitable here?

Most likely, yes.